# Auth0 Logout not working in Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, auth0, java-17

I am following the [QuickStart for auth0 with Spring Boot 2](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-spring-boot-login-samples), but my project is using Spring Boot 3, after changing the deprecated methods logout doesn't work anymore.

Security Config:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final LogoutHandler logoutHandler;

    public SecurityConfig(LogoutHandler logoutHandler) {
        this.logoutHandler = logoutHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/images/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().oauth2Login()
                .and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler);
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

LogoutHandler:

```
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;
import java.io.IOException;

@Controller
public class LogoutHandler extends SecurityContextLogoutHandler {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private final ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

    @Autowired
    public LogoutHandler(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        this.clientRegistrationRepository = clientRegistrationRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void logout(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                       Authentication authentication) {

        super.logout(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, authentication);
        String issuer = (String) getClientRegistration().getProviderDetails().getConfigurationMetadata().get("issuer");
        String clientId = getClientRegistration().getClientId();
        String returnTo = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().build().toString();

        String logoutUrl = UriComponentsBuilder
                .fromHttpUrl(issuer + "v2/logout?client_id={clientId}&returnTo={returnTo}")
                .encode()
                .buildAndExpand(clientId, returnTo)
                .toUriString();

        log.info("Will attempt to redirect to logout URL: {}", logoutUrl);
        try {
            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(logoutUrl);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            log.error("Error redirecting to logout URL", ioe);
        }
    }
    
    private ClientRegistration getClientRegistration() {
        return this.clientRegistrationRepository.findByRegistrationId("auth0");
    }
}
```

When I log out, I don't get redirected and it shows: [You have been signed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bptrT.png)
But I can still access protected resources and if I go to my /profile endpoint I can see my profile like I am logged in. This doesn't happen when I run the QuickStart with Spring Boot 2, everything works fine, all my configuration (client-secret, client-id, issuer-uri, callbacks and logout urls are configured correctly and are the same for the Spring Boot 3 app, I double checked). Any help would be appreciated, I can't find tutorials with Spring Boot 3 and Auth0.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working with Spring Boot 3.0.4 for a similar application. I'm using the latest okta-spring-boot starter, but I don't think it matters. Can you try the below for handling logout?

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.auth0.issuer-uri}")
    private String issuer;
    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.auth0.client-id}")
    private String clientId;

    LogoutHandler oidcLogoutHandler() {
        return (request, response, authentication) -> {
            try {
                response.sendRedirect( issuer + "v2/logout?client_id=" + clientId + "&returnTo=http://localhost:8080/");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                // allow anonymous access to the root page
                .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
                // authenticate all other requests
                .anyRequest().authenticated());
        // configure logout handler
        http.logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).addLogoutHandler(oidcLogoutHandler());
        // enable OAuth2/OIDC
        http.oauth2Login();
        // enable Resource Server for API access
        http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: The doc recommends to set the logout **success** handler: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/reactive/oauth2/login/advanced.html#webflux-oauth2-login-advanced-oidc-logout

Answer (score 0):

To also invalidate the session on the OIDC Provider (OP or OAuth2 authorization server) when a session is invalidated on a Relying Party (RP or OAuth2 client) you should use [RP-Initiated Logout](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.htm).

Spring has [logout success handlers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/servlet/oauth2/login/advanced.html#oauth2login-advanced-oidc-logout) for that: `OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler` (with an equivalent for reactive apps [documented there](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/reactive/oauth2/login/advanced.html#webflux-oauth2-login-advanced-oidc-logout)).

The thing is that, out of the box, Auth0 does not follow the OIDC standard on two points ([but maybe it does if you contact the support](https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/login/logout/log-users-out-of-auth0)):

- [.well-known/openid-configuration](https://dev-ch4mpy.eu.auth0.com/) is missing `end_session_endpoint`. The logout endpoint is `{issuer-uri}v2/logout` (in my case: `https://dev-ch4mpy.eu.auth0.com/v2/logout`).
- the parameter to tell where to redirect after logout is named `returnTo` and not `post_logout_redirect_uri` as it should

So, you'll have to write your own `ServerLogoutSuccessHandler` in addition to configuring it like in the doc linked above. You may take inspiration from the other answer to write this handler, just remember to change the implemented interface (or to extend `SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler`).

[I have written thin wrappers](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/) around `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`. It exposes such a logout success handler that you can configure from properties:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-starter-oidc</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    // Yes, that's all, logout is configured in YAML 
    // with the rest of the security filter-chain
}
```

```yaml
api-host: ${scheme}://localhost:${server.port}
ui-host: ${api-host}

scheme: http
auth0-issuer: https://dev-ch4mpy.eu.auth0.com/
autho-secret: change-me

server:
  port: 8080
  ssl:
    enabled: false
      
spring:
  lifecycle:
    timeout-per-shutdown-phase: 30s
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          auth0:
            issuer-uri: ${auth0-issuer}
        registration:
          auth0-confidential-user:
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            client-name: Auth0
            client-id: TyY0H7xkRMRe6lDf9F8EiNqCo8PdhICy
            client-secret: ${autho-secret}
            provider: auth0
            scope: openid,profile,email,offline_access

com:
  c4-soft:
    springaddons:
      oidc:
        ops:
        - iss: ${auth0-issuer}
          username-claim: $['https://c4-soft.com/spring-addons']['name']
          authorities:
          - path: $.roles
          - path: $.permissions
        client:
          security-matchers:
          - /**
          permit-all:
          - /login/**
          - /oauth2/**
          - /
          - /ui/**
          - /swagger-ui.html
          - /swagger-ui/**
          client-uri: ${ui-host}
          post-login-redirect-path: /ui/greet
          post-logout-redirect-path: /ui/greet
          oauth2-logout:
            - client-registration-id: auth0-confidential-user
              uri: ${auth0-issuer}v2/logout
              client-id-request-param: client_id
              post-logout-uri-request-param: returnTo
---
scheme: https

server:
  ssl:
    enabled: true

spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: ssl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda expression:

```
.logout((logout)
    -> logout.logoutUrl("/api/v1/auth/logout")
    .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler)
    .logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()))
  .build();
```